# AttributeError: 'GqlQuery' object has no attribute 'Key'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

How do I retrieve and display the keys for several results returned from a GQL query?

**main.py**

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):          

        author = "William Shakespeare"

        q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Book " +
                        "WHERE author = :1 ", author)
        keys = q.Key

        template_values = { 
            'author': author,
            'key': key,         
        }       

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

When I use

```
keys = q.key()
```

I get this error:

> File "C:\programming_google_app_engine_repo\datastore\main.py", line
>   17, in get
>       key = q.key() AttributeError: 'GqlQuery' object has no attribute 'key'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one issue with your code. Please take a step back and think about what you want to do and skim over the documentation once more.

**Problem 1**
The result of a `GqlQuery` does NOT have a key. You need to use `.get()` or `.fetch(1)` to access the `Book` object.

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Book WHERE author = :1 ", author)
my_book = q.get()
```

**Problem 2**
To get the value of a `method` you need to remember to include the parens/brackets.

```
my_book_key = my_book.key() # don't forget the parens/brackets

template_values = { 
    'author': author,
    'key': my_book_key,         
}
```